# Granting Permissions for Camera and Audio to WebView?

Tags: android, webview, illegalstateexception

I have implemented `WebChromeClient` and from `onPermissionRequest` I couldn't access to the Camera and Audio inside the app.

My Code iS

```
@Override
    public void onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request) {
        super.onPermissionRequest(request);

        final String[] requestedResources = request.getResources();
        for (String r : requestedResources) {
            if ((r.equals(PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE)) || r.equals(PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_AUDIO_CAPTURE)) {
                request.grant(new String[]{PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE,PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_AUDIO_CAPTURE});
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

But I keep getting an exception and error as below

```
> W/System.err: **java.lang.IllegalStateException**: **Either grant() or
> deny() has been already called**. W/System.err:     at
> org.chromium.android_webview.permission.AwPermissionRequest.b(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-1:3)
>         at org.chromium.android_webview.permission.AwPermissionRequest.a(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-1:1)
>         at xe.deny(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-1:1)
>         at com.royalconx.MainActivity$MyChromeClient.onPermissionRequest(MainActivity.java:96)
>         at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.onPermissionRequest(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-1:9)
> W/System.err:     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native
> Method)
>         at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:363)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

Answer (score 3):

if you have `super` call in first line

```
super.onPermissionRequest(request)
```

then probably you can't "manually" call `grant` or `deny` again like you trying next in loop. move your code above `super` call and be sure that `super` won't be called for perms handled by yourself - make prepared `PermissionRequest` without these, if not empty (any other perms requested) then call `super` with this modified request

also be sure that whole app has proper perms acquired already